# Kafka Streams - Efficient computation of min/max on KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In a Kafka Streams application, we have a **KTable** (not a KStream) in which we want to compute some statistics such as minimum or maximum of all "rows"/entries that fulfill a certain property. Therefore, we transform the KTable into a KGroupedTable by setting the property for grouping as key. Using this grouped table, it is now simple to compute something like count or sum. We just have to use the `aggregate` method with specific appropriate adder and substractor functions. (+/- 1 for counting, +/- the value for sum).

For aggregations such as min/max, however, there is no such simple substractor function. One solution to implement min/max aggregations would be to aggregate the value to something like a map, where the adder function is *adding to the map* and substracting is *removing from the map*. Than in a consecutive step, we can `map` this map to the min/max value by simply iterating over the entries.

```java
// Example without types and serdes
KTable sums = myKTable.groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getProperty(), v)
                      .aggregate(() -> 0, (k, v, a) -> a + v.getValue(), , (k, v, a) -> a - v.getValue();

KTable mins = myKTable.groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getProperty(), v)
                      .aggregate(() -> Map.of(), (k, v, a) -> a.put(v.getId(), v.getValue()), , (k, v, a) -> a.remove(v.getId())
                      .mapValues((k, v) -> StatsHelper.min(v));
```

This however does not feel really *smooth* as we would have to serialize the whole map with all its entries the whole time. Are there any nicer approaches to achieve this, i.e., getting all the relevant "rows" directly by the framework? Or is this simply not feasible?

Comment: Using `Map` is the only way -- as you mentioned, max/min is not subtractible and thus requires to store all raw values.

Comment: Is this only the current (v2.1) implementation or is it a conscious decision required by the Kafka Streams architecture? As the deployment instance, which performs the aggregation for a given key, must have received every relevant message (the "rows to aggregate) with this key previously, I expect that it is possible to store these values in this instance. For example, in the corresponding key-value store; similar to the aggregation results itself. Or am I missing something? @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: It not related to the architecture. Kafka Streams could support this out-of-the-box; it's just not implemented this way atm.

Comment: Wouldn't the solution here be: ktable.map(...).toStream().groupByKey().aggregate(...) ?

Comment: no way it can be solution - KStream isn't aware of row deletes and changes, it's just a stream of immutable data. KTable is aware of them but this comes at cost: no way to compute maximum. You can try approximating the max some way: ignoring deletes, by keeping e.g. 1000 items or using LogSumExp or p-norm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) - but those are all approximations, which can fail terribly in specific corner cases